# Name for a tree where nodes hold a reference to their parent as well as their children

Tags: naming, trees

I am creating a tree where some nodes have a reference to their parent as well as their children. It feels like a tree version of a doubly linked list.

Is there a name for this?

Comment: What do you mean **some** nodes have a parent reference?

Comment: A family tree ?

Comment: MSell - The nodes are of different type derived from `Node`. Some of these types need a parent reference and others do not.

Comment: Mouviciel - Is 'family tree' a name that you are suggesting or a name that you know to be already established?

Comment: @StephenHewlett - I think "family tree" was meant as a joke. See: genealogy. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a *official* name for it.

I would call it "tree with back pointer", or more specific "B-Tree with back pointer" ...

I found also the names [`Doubly-Linked Lists`](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15745-s03/public/suif1/html/suif1_95.html#SEC95) and [`Tree Node List`](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15745-s03/public/suif1/html/suif1_20.html). According to it, you could call *Doubly-Linked Tree*

Comment: I've never heard Doubly-Linked Tree before but its meaning is perfectly clear.

Comment: +1 because I agree, if someone said "doubly linked tree" I'd know immidiatly that it had a reference to its parent and its child because of doubly linked lists.

Comment: @NathanC.Tresch - actually, I'd find this unclear, because it could imply that the children of a parent form a doubly-linked list ... or something.

Comment: I think 'doubly-linked tree' is the best so far.

Comment: @StephenC You mean, each of the child-nodes of a parent would reference each-other in a doubly-linked list? Wouldn't that make it no longer a tree?

Comment: I think it would still be a tree, but one that would support a particular form of backwards traversal more efficiently than normal.

Comment: @StephenHewlett I think I was interpreting that a different way. It seemed like Stephen C was suggesting it would be a tree where each child has a reference to another child under the same parent, rather than a reference back to its own parent. I'd agree that a tree where the child has a reference to its parent is still a valid tree.

Comment: @StephenHewlett I guess what you're describing is kind of a tree, but, I'm not sure that "tree" impiles anything other than something like a btree structure, and linked list implies a peer structure.